# Universal Analytics: Client ID

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

The [documentation about Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) states that it must be a UUID

```
Example usage: cid=35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b
```

But when looking at the calls that analytics.js is issuing, I see that the value has another format:

```
cid:714937391.1406537193
```

What are those values? and how are they generated? Can I use the same value if I want to append events to that session from a different application?

Is the Client ID used as the session identifier?

Comment: I suspect someone in the Google Analytics G+ community could answer this.  https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114481059214254340537

Comment: Some more info from Google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-measurement-protocol/eYgtS5VmrVY

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading. The client ID doesn't technically need to be a UUID hash in that format. It's merely suggesting that format to help people avoid generating duplicate client IDs by accident.

The format of the client ID in analytics.js is a randomly generated 31-bit integer followed by a dot (".") followed by the current time in seconds.

If you wanted to generate a client ID in this format yourself (for whatever reason) you could do something like the following:

```
var cid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x7FFFFFFF) + "." + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

To answer your other question, yes, you can use the same client ID in a server-side [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol) hit as you find in the cookie generated by analytics.js and the sessions will be linked.

Furthermore, if you wanted to make sure your server-side hits were as closely linked to your client-side hit as possible, you should also use the [User Agent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua) and [IP override](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uip) fields, which are new to the measurement protocol. If you don't, then all the geo data for your server-side hits will look like it came from wherever your server is located.

**UPDATE**

Also, in case it's not clear how to get the client ID from JavaScript, here's what [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) recommends:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Note that it recommends **not** reading the data directly from the cookie.